# Pandas DataFrame style with mixed type yields TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame with mixed types and I would like to color the cells only on the first 4 rows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4],
                      columns = ['A','B'],             
                      data=np.random.uniform(low=0.,
                      high=1.,size=8).reshape(4,2)
                      )
>>> df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(index=[5],
                       columns=['A','B'],
                       data=[['OK', 'OK']])])
>>> df
           A           B
1   0.548814    0.715189
2   0.602763    0.544883
3   0.423655    0.645894
4   0.437587    0.891773
5         OK          OK
```

Using the `subset` to only apply the style only on the first 4 rows, this returns me an error:

```
>>> df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',
                         low=0.6, 
                         high=0.8, 
                         subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:4,:])
TypeError: ("Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'", 'occurred at index A')
```

Any idea of a workaround?

I'm using Pandas 0.22.0

thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported in `style`s yet.

Possible solution is convert non numeric to `NaN`s:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

And if necessary highlight it:

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',
                         low=0.6, 
                         high=0.8, 
                         subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:4,:]).highlight_null('red')
```

[image: pic]